# Unable to cast ObjectParameter to Nullable DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable

```
var OverDate = new ObjectParameter("OverDate",(DateTime)DateTime.Now);
DateTime? convertedDate = (DateTime?) OverDate.Value;
```

It able to build but throwing runtime exception when I provide `convertedDate` as input parameter of type `DateTime?`

May I know which part of the conversion was wrong as I get the below exception

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter'
>   to type 'System.IConvertible'

Comment: Your code works fine (.net 4.5)

Comment: It able to build but throwing runtime exception when I provide `convertedDate` as input parameter of type `DateTime?`

Comment: Maybe you should check `Nullable<DateTime>` ?

Comment: No, I mean that it actually works. http://img.leprosorium.com/2480316

Comment: Also `var cast = (IConvertible)OverDate.Value` works in the above case. So the question fails to reproduce the problem. We can both down-cast the box from `object` to `IConvertible`, and unbox into `DateTime`, and also unbox followed by wrapping into `DateTime?`. It must be that either (A) you have forgotten `.Value` on your `ObjectParameter`, or (B) your have one `ObjectParameter` wrapped inside another `ObjectParameter`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
DateTime? convertedDate = OverDate.Value as DateTime?;
```

Comment: Tried it on 4.0 and it works just fine for me. Try using those two lines in new project and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get an error with the following code.  Try creating new project with code below.  Sometimes when an exception occurs in a program and you don't have an exception handler (try/catch) the code skip around giving confusing error messages.  You may have an exception some place else in your project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
//add reference for System.Data.Entity
using System.Data.Objects;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var OverDate = new ObjectParameter("OverDate", (DateTime)DateTime.Now);
            DateTime? convertedDate = (DateTime?)OverDate.Value;
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: @jdweng: I do have try/catch exception handler and it's the catch part that showing me the error I mentioned

Comment: If you don't have an exception handle in another section of the code Net Library will jump to another section of the code where there is an exception handler.  When an exception occurs the Net library moves up the execution stack until it finds the first exception handler. The VS compiler puts an exception handler before calling main() so there is always a default exception handler to prevent Blue Screen Failures.